# bootloader's messages and bootm.c

Tags: boot-loader

When I boot linux on zynq board, one of the line that I get is;

```
Starting kernel . . .
```

For debugging purpose I wanted to know where in the source code these lines are written, I would change them and then add printf/printk statements at various points to debug my linux kernel. I found that in the bootm.c file it was indeed written. But I also found this 'fake' stuff here which I am uanble to understand.

```
/**
 * announce_and_cleanup() - Print message and prepare for kernel boot
 *
 * @fake: non-zero to do everything except actually boot
 */
static void announce_and_cleanup(int fake)
{
        printf("\n Starting kernel ...%s\n\n", fake ?
                "(fake run for tracing)" : "");
        bootstage_mark_name(BOOTSTAGE_ID_BOOTM_HANDOFF, "start_kernel");
#ifdef CONFIG_BOOTSTAGE_FDT
           if (flag == BOOTM_STATE_OS_FAKE_GO)
                bootstage_fdt_add_report();
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_BOOTSTAGE_REPORT
        bootstage_report();
#endif
```

the complete file is available [here](http://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/#uboot/arch/arm/lib/bootm.c) also

What exactly is this 'fake' stuf and why do we need it?

Answer (score 0):

The `announce_and_cleanup` routine doesn't use its `fake` parameter except for printing the "(fake run for tracing)" or not. In particular, it doesn't pass it on to the functions it calls after `printf()`.
The parameter comment for `fake` says non-zero means do everything except actually boot, and the difference in `printf()` cannot be the cause for that.

If you look at where `announce_and_cleanup()` is being called, then `fake` might be a bit clearer (from the same file you link to):

```
 248/* Subcommand: GO */
 249static void boot_jump_linux(bootm_headers_t *images, int flag)
 250{
 251#ifdef CONFIG_ARM64
 252        void (*kernel_entry)(void *fdt_addr);
 253        int fake = (flag & BOOTM_STATE_OS_FAKE_GO);
 254
 255        kernel_entry = (void (*)(void *fdt_addr))images->ep;
 256
 257        debug("## Transferring control to Linux (at address %lx)...\n",
 258                (ulong) kernel_entry);
 259        bootstage_mark(BOOTSTAGE_ID_RUN_OS);
 260
 261        announce_and_cleanup(fake);
 262
 263        if (!fake)
 264                kernel_entry(images->ft_addr);
 265#else
 266        unsigned long machid = gd->bd->bi_arch_number;
 267        char *s;
 268        void (*kernel_entry)(int zero, int arch, uint params);
 269        unsigned long r2;
 270        int fake = (flag & BOOTM_STATE_OS_FAKE_GO);
 271
 272        kernel_entry = (void (*)(int, int, uint))images->ep;
 273
 274        s = getenv("machid");
 275        if (s) {
 276                strict_strtoul(s, 16, &machid);
 277                printf("Using machid 0x%lx from environment\n", machid);
 278        }
 279
 280        debug("## Transferring control to Linux (at address %08lx)" \
 281                "...\n", (ulong) kernel_entry);
 282        bootstage_mark(BOOTSTAGE_ID_RUN_OS);
 283        announce_and_cleanup(fake);
 284
 285        if (IMAGE_ENABLE_OF_LIBFDT && images->ft_len)
 286                r2 = (unsigned long)images->ft_addr;
 287        else
 288                r2 = gd->bd->bi_boot_params;
 289
 290        if (!fake)
 291                kernel_entry(0, machid, r2);
 292#endif
 293}
```

if fake is non-zero for `announce_and_cleanup()`, the `kernel_entry()` is never called and the program control flow does not transfer to the loaded kernel.